# Bind event to insert elements in existing Tkinter Tree

Tags: python, tkinter, tree

I'm trying to build a scheduler for my bills.

Clicking on NEW, or bi-clicking on an tree element, a new window will pop up to edit or add new element.

My problem is here: how can I tell to my code to add the new or to change the old?

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import sys
import os.path

tree_nr_columns = 5
tree_columns = ("date","payee","dex","every","amount")
tree_width = (100, 200, 250, 50, 100)
tree_anchor = ("c","w","w","c","e")
tree_txt = []
for i in range(0, tree_nr_columns):
    tree_txt.append(" ")
file_name = "/media/tony/Vault/scadenziario.txt"

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        frame2 = Frame(master)
        frame2.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)
        self.tree["columns"] = tree_columns
        self.tree['show'] = 'headings' # remove the first empty column
        for i in range(0, tree_nr_columns):
            self.tree.column(tree_columns[i], width = tree_width[i], anchor = tree_anchor[i])
            self.tree.heading(tree_columns[i], text=tree_columns[i])
        self.tree.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnDoubleClick)

        self.button_quit = Button(frame2, text = "EXIT", width = 10, command = self.B_Exit).pack(side = LEFT)
        self.button_quit = Button(frame2, text = "DELETE", width = 10).pack(side = LEFT)
        self.button_quit = Button(frame2, text = "NEW", width = 10, command = self.B_ManageEnterWindow).pack(side = LEFT)

        self.FileRW("R")        

    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        manageEnterWindow(self.tree.item(item,"values"))

    def B_ManageEnterWindow(self):
        manageEnterWindow(0)
        print "X"

    def FileRW(self, value):
        if value == "R":
            if os.path.isfile(file_name):
                self.tree.insert("" , END, text="001", values=("2017 04 11" , "VODAFONE" , "bolletta telefono" , "1y" , "60.50")) 
                #~ f = open(file_name, 'r')
                #~ while True:
                    #~ x = f.readline()
                    #~ if x == "":
                        #~ break
                    #~ x = x[:-1]
                    #~ self.tree.insert("" , END, text="001", values=(x))
            else:
                pass
                #~ f = open(file_name, 'w')
                #~ f.close()

        if value == "W":
            pass
            #~ f = open(file_name, 'w')
            #~ for child in self.tree.get_children():
                #~ a = ""
                #~ for x in self.tree.item(child)["values"]:
                    #~ a = a + ' "' + x + '" '
                #~ a = a[1:-1] + "\n"
                #~ f.write(a) 
            #~ f.close

    def B_Exit(self):
        self.FileRW("W")
        exit()

class EnterWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, values):
        for i in range(0, tree_nr_columns):
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack(side = TOP)
            Label(frame, text=tree_columns[i], width = 8, anchor = W).pack(side = LEFT, fill = X)
            if values:
                tree_txt[i] = Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar(frame, values[i]))
            else:
                tree_txt[i] = Entry(frame)
            tree_txt[i].pack(side = RIGHT, fill = X, expand = True)

        tree_txt[0].focus_set()

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.button_quit = Button(frame, text = "BACK", width = 10, command = self.B_Exit).pack(side = LEFT)
        self.button_quit = Button(frame, text = "CONFIRM", width = 10, command = self.B_Confirm).pack(side = LEFT)
        #~ root2.mainloop()

    def B_Confirm(self):
        #~ tree.insert("" , END, text="001", values=("2017 04 11" , "VODAFONE" , "bolletta telefono" , "1y" , "60.50")) 
        for i in range(0, tree_nr_columns):
            print i, tree_txt[i].get()
        self.B_Exit()

    def B_Exit(self):
        root2.destroy()

def manageEnterWindow(values):
    global root2
    try:
        x = root2.state() is not None
        root2.lift()
        root2.focus_force()
    except:
        root2 = Tk()
        app = EnterWindow(root2,values)
    root2.mainloop()

root = Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just add another button for CHG. For tree element double-clicking, you'll need to first pop-up a dialog that asks the user which operation they want to do. You could also implement a right-click pop-up context menu that had the two choices on it.

Comment: No, sorry but I think that I was not clear. My problem is that I don't know how to code the "**tree.insert**" when the user click on [CONFIRM].

Comment: OK, in that case, what is it that you want "to add the new or to change the old"?

Comment: When the user clicks on [CONFIRM] in the second window, the code executes **"def B_Confirm(self):"**
At this level, I cannot simply use **tree.insert(...)** like (only for testing purpose, it is not the real code) **tree.insert("" , END, text="001", values=("2017 04 11" , "VODAFONE" , "bolletta telefono" , "1y" , "60.50"))** 

The error I get is: **global name 'tree' is not defined**

I know, I miss something.

Comment: You need to make the `MainWindow` instance's `self.tree` attribute available to the  `EnterWindow.B_Confirm()` method somehow when it's called. It looks like that could be done if it were passed as an argument to `manageEnterWindow()` when that's called from `MainWindow.OnDoubleClick()`, and then from there on to the `EnterWindow` instance that's created. Doing all that is why many folks just use global variables.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error that you are getting with your code. That error is telling you something useful.

Comment: TonyIT: please don't try to add code in the comments. It's impossible to read.

Comment: @martineau That works!  I just passed the id of the tree, self.tree, as argument. Great! Your suggestion rocks! Thank's a lot. :-)

Comment: @TonyIT: That's good news (especially since you didn't end up using a global `;-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem: As Martineau suggested, I passed the id of the tree, *self.tree*, as argument.

As example:

```
def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
item = self.tree.selection()[0]
manageEnterWindow(self.tree, self.tree.item(item,"values"))
```

And so (only for example too, not the real code):

```
def B_Confirm(self, tree_id):
tree_id.insert("" , END, text="001", values=("A","B","C","D","E")) 
self.B_Exit()
```